# Определение типа значения в строке из XML

Tags: php, simplexml

Имеется XML документ, из него идет парсинг значений полей и далее необходимо узнать тип значения записанный в строковой переменной. Для определения типа значения в переменной написал такую функцию.

```
public function getTypeValue($var) {

    if (is_numeric($var)) {

        if (is_int($var)) {
            return 'int';
        }elseif (is_integer($var)){
            return 'integer';
        }elseif (is_long($var)){
            return 'long';
        }elseif (is_float($var)){
            return 'float';
        }elseif (is_double($var)){
            return 'double';
        }else{
            return "len: " . strlen($var);
        }

    }else{

        return 'string';

    }

}
```

Как ни крути, там где строки, выдает `string`, там где числа (014982, 2, 3, 3.1.3 и т.п.) функция выдает информацию по длинне строки но не тип. Блок `else` для чисел сделал для проверки нет ли посторонних символов в строке, которые бы мешали. По результатам видно что ничего постороннего там нету.
Если взять обычный массив и заполнить данными то функция отрабатывает верно, то есть определяет и строки и числа разного типа. Как побороть ситуацию?

Код обработки XML:

```
public function parse() {       

    $fullpath = PATH_XMLFOLDER . "/linecheck.xml";

    $xml = simplexml_load_file($fullpath);
    $fields = $xml->xpath('//fields/*');

    foreach ($fields as $field) {

        $fieldName = (string)$field->getName();

        $value = (string)$field;
        $typeValue = $this->getTypeValue($value);           

        SVTools::sv_debug($value,0);
        SVTools::sv_debug($typeValue,0);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После

```
if (is_numeric($var)) {
```

поставьте

```
   $var = 0 + $var;
```

**P.S.** `is_int()` === `is_integer()` === `is_long()` и `is_float()` === `is_double()`

Comment: `if (is_numeric($var)) {` отрабатывает верно.

Comment: Про алиасы функций известно.

Comment: Вы описание функций читали? is_numeric() срабатывает и на строке, и на числе. Все остальные функции только на числах! Для этого строку и переводить в число надо.

Answer (score -1):

XML сам по себе не имеет поддержки описания типов данных. Поэтому все скалярные значения будут строками. Всегда.

Приводить к какому-то типу данных и его валидировать соответственно этому вы должны уже основываясь на знаниях, что именно вы хотите найти в этом документе.

Comment: Перечитайте вопрос... речь про значения а не про типы переменных. Речь не про привидение типов, а про определение типа Значения.

Comment: Ещё раз: в XML есть только строки и никаких других типов скаляров. Поэтому тип переменной после XML-парсера будет всегда строковым.

Comment: Вы издеваетесь? Я это знаю, ваш ответ неуместен и комментарии ибо вы не правильно трактуете вопрос.

Comment: Если вы знаете, что получите строку, то почему проверяя тип переменной удивляетесь, что оно вдруг оказалось не числом? Утверждаете, что вопрос не про приведение типов и принимаете ответ про приведение типов. Понятно, конечно - вы просто не читали мануал и реально вопрос про is_int. Мой ответ о том, что вообще не надо пытаться угадать, к какому типу нужно приводить значение. Вы уже знаете, что в таком-то элементе рассчитываете найти целое число - и исходя из этого и надо проверять, что в строке находится целое число, может быть в каком-то диапазоне. Для этого предназначены функции filter_var.

Comment: SO не предназначен для общих ответов типо вашего, как и для общих вопросов. Поэтому вам наверное надо было дать четкий ответ, как разрешить ситуацию технически, то есть привидением вашего решения в виде кода а не советов.